# Is there a second level (yellow/orange) Matrix in The Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

In the last episode of The Matrix trilogy, when Neo becomes blind, he sees a yellow/orange Matrix (as opposed to “regular” Matrix, the green one) in what is supposed to be the real world. He has powers he used to only have in the Matrix.

Are there clear explanations of this? I have two hypotheses:

1. What is said to be the “real world” is another matrix (yellow/orange), which contains the other one (the green one). Neo has root access to this matrix, hence the control over machines.
2. He has some sort of wireless connection to the machines system, therefore he can control them outside the Matrix.

I find the second one more convincing. I prefer the first one. It means we never see the real world in any of the movies.

Edit: the question was marked as duplicate to a complementary, but different question: how can Neo control the machine while he is not connected to The Matrix. This is not my question, this one of the facts that leads me to my question.

The discussion with the Oracle and the Architect mentions the source. This suggests the yellow/orange things which appears when Neo is in the “real world” is the source, as opposed to the Matrix (green). However looking at our world (the real real, outside the fiction) you have programs, their source, both on a computer, which is part of the world. Both sources and programs are “virtual”.

The wireless hypothesis means Neo's plug has something special that makes it possible for him to communicate with the machines' system in some way. So he can be both in the “real world” and the “meta Matrix” which contains both the source and the running programs. But if he can connect wirelessly, why does he have to protecting the core part of the Matrix?

What puzzles me, and makes me think about the other hypothesis is the mention to these several reboots of the systems, and previous occurrences of Neo facing the Architect (as depicted on the screens). How can this be the same person in the physical world? Is he a clone? Why did it have to be a clone? What makes his physical body critical for it, as opposed to his counterpart (program) in the Matrix? With the first hypothesis, Neo is a meta program of the yellow/orange matrix, hence he is just patched between reboots. This quote of the Oracle can be interpreted as a mention to another Matrix including the Matrix.

> **Oracle**: The power of the One extends beyond this world. It reaches
>   from here all the way back to where it came from.

What are the actual facts leading to the wireless hypothesis?

Comment: It's augmented reality. Note that he can only see active machine elements

Comment: The first explanation was a popular theory after the second movie, but in the third it was pretty well established that it was the second explanation that was correct.

Comment: @Valorum AR plus #2 at least.

Comment: This question is similar to the one marked as duplicate, but it does not answer the question. I edited my question to extend my point.

Comment: Can anybody remove this [duplicate] tag and allow answers again? This is a different question. It is frustrating somebody decided on his own my question was answered. Please let me judge this myself.

Comment: Answering why The One looks the same in all the Architect monitors, you are not seeing older versions, just simulations. Also notice when he says he is the 6th version, he shows more than 6 different reactions in the back. I think the monitors are just illustrative, and sometimes represent what his predictions for Neo's reactions. For example, during the "Bullshit" part, he says "Denial is the most predictable of all human emotion", showing various Neos saying bullshit, but acting moving different. They are not supposed to show other The Ones, just possibilities, or in Matrix-speak "choices".